# Getting rid of progress indicator in status bar on ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

On ie8 there is a green progress indicator below on the status bar, likely indicating download progression based on some static length value from somewhere. Unfortunately due to the nature of "modern" dynamic javascripts, ajax calls etc. this indicator often gets messed up and the bar stays at half full. Is there a way to turn that progress bar off through a javascript command or at least tell the browser we are done so please go away? I know the status bar can be turned off completely, however I still have a need for it to display my own status messages etc.

[image: ie8ProgressBar]

Comment: Do you have any errors in your scripts?

Comment: Not that I know of, it doesn't get tripped by the debugger, might be a catch somewhere that I don't know about, using a 3rd party library for the gui stuff. It shows Done all the way to the left, not error indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after some trial and errors I think I finally figured out how to trick ie8 to think it's done loading. I'm sure there might be other more elegant solutions out there, which I would be happy to hear about.

In the web page root root I created an empty html doc called blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

In the view/html for the form/page/window I create an invisible iframe

```
<iframe id="iframeHack" name="iframeHack" frameborder="0"
    style="height: 0; width: 0" src="blank.html">
</iframe>
```

in the javascript section of that view I place a timebomb

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    .
    .
    .

    setTimeout("document.getElementById('iframeHack').src = 'blank.html'", 100);
</script>
```